# pass a parameter to a pytest fixture for teardown

Tags: pytest, fixtures

The problem:
*Clean up test artifacts created from the test. In the case below how can a single row created during a test be deleted from the database using a pytest fixture? (Not everything should be deleted from the table after every run. Otherwise a Delete all rows or drop table could be used). The row identifier of the created row is saved in a function variable during the test.*

Is it possible to pass a variable created during the test as a parameter into a fixture in pytest? The fixture needs to always run whether the test completed either by it failing or succeeding. The row identifier won’t be known until the test is ran.

Problem illustrated with a fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def clean_up_db_row(row_id):
    yield
    delete_from_db(self.row_id). # code to delete the row based on the id


def test_something_added_to_database(clean_up_db_row):
    row_id = create_db_row()  # function under test
    ...
    assert row_id in db  # test that information added to the database

    # the clean_up_db_row fixture will always run but how will it know about the id variable defined in the function?
```

If an assert fails halfway through a test the row added during the test doesn’t get deleted when tacking the clean up to the end. Because the test stop executing.

Example of the problem is with out a pytest fixture:

```py
def clean_up_db_row(row_id):
    yield
    delete_from_db(row_id). # code to delete the row based on the id


def test_something_added_to_database():
    row_id = create_db_row()  # function under test
    ...
    assert row_id in db  # test that information added to the database
    clean_up_db_row(row_id)  # this won’t run if there is a failure
```

Solution without a pytest fixture

```py
def clean_up_db_row(row_id):
    yield
    delete_from_db(row_id). # code to delete the row based on the id

def test_something_added_to_database():
    row_id = create_db_row()  # function under test
    ...
    try:
        assert row_id in db  # test that information added to the database
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        clean_up_db_row(row_id)  # this will always run but doesn’t use a fixture
```

Potential solution using an instance variable on a class

```py
class TestCaseCleanUp:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def clean_up_db_row(self):
        yield
        delete_from_db(self.row_id). # code to delete the row based on the id


    def test_something_added_to_database(self):
        self.row_id = create_db_row()  # function under test
        ...
        assert self.row_id in db  # test that information added to the database
        # the autouse fixture can use the self.row_id assigned
```

Comment: @wim you’re right. I was looking up autouse fixtures thinking I was using them but didn’t put it in the question or in my actual code. Reflecting on how autouse fixtures are used. Should I be putting the test in a class with the autouse fixture then assign the row_id to the class like `self.row_id = create_db_row()`. In the fixture I can then use the `self.row_id` variable.

Comment: @wim just updated it. I tried to make it as clear as I could.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your goal.  I'll add an answer.  But this has nothing to do with autouse fixtures, this is just a regular fixture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The object yielded by a fixture is *injected* into the test context by the runner.  This can be any object you want, and the test is free to mutate it.

Here is a pattern that should work for you:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def clean_up_db_rows():
    row_ids = []
    yield row_ids
    for row_id in row_ids:
        delete_from_db(row_id)


def test_something_added_to_database(clean_up_db_rows):
    row_id = create_db_row()  # function under test
    clean_up_db_rows.append(row_id)
    ...
    assert row_id in db  # test that information added to the database
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Daaamn) 200IQ solution :) Thanks

Comment: How/Can you do this with "regular" yielded variables? for example mutate False yield to True

Comment: @igor Get/set it inside a container instead, for example in a dict.

Comment: This is gold ! What an underrated answer :) thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3403):

> Create a class in conftest.py and import it in your test module. To protect yourself from errors caused by failed testcases that were suppose to add values in the class, assign None to all the known values.

### conftest.py:

```
class ValueStorage:
    value1 = None
    value2 = None
```

### test_mytest.py:

```
from conftest import ValueStorage

def test_one():
    ValueStorage.value1 = "anything you want here"
def test_two():
    assert ValueStorage.value1 == "anything you want here"
    ValueStorage.value2 = ValueStorage.value1

class TestClass:
    def test_three(self):
        assert ValueStorage.value1 == ValueStorage.value2
```

> You can pass dictionaries and lists and anything you feel like. If you require persistence (want the values to be kept from one run to another you can write them in a json file or use the cache option)